# Accepted job offer via e-mail, no response after. When should I follow up?

Tags: job-offer

Got the job offer via e-mail which I've never experienced before since it had always been in person on my past two jobs. I replied to the e-mail and accepted the offer but with a few questions at the end. I received that on the weekend and it's Tuesday now and no response yet. I always follow up to them even before, I'm always the one who reaches out first and not them. I don't want to do that again and bug them and they might find me annoying.

Should I worry if I don't receive a reply tomorrow?

Comment: In Offer did they mention some helpful information? i.e Date of joining

Comment: @HelpingHands No start date. Just mentioned the job description and my starting salary and how many months I will be probationary and the benefits.

Comment: I don't know where you live but it is Christmas week.

Comment: @Frisbee Yeah that's what I thought too. Im sure theyre busy as hell so Im thinking of not following up yet. Maybe after Christmas?

Comment: @Frisbee - I agree. May be they are on Christmas vacation.

Comment: @HelpingHands ok yeah ill do it next week

Comment: @user45100 - Yes that would be great.

Comment: @HelpingHands I couldnt help it. I emailed her this morning. But not to follow up but i just gave her my official end date of on my current employer. just so she wont forget about me.

Comment: Nice one , May be she will be back to you after christmas. in new year first week you could expect call from them.

Comment: @HelpingHands They totally will! haha i hope. Anyway, is that email job offer binding?

Comment: Might be.... :)

Answer (score 6):

> Got the job offer via email which Ive never experienced before since
>   its always in person on my past two jobs.

It's quite common to receive one, so you don't need to freak out here. Congrats!

However, companies mostly call you before or after the mail is sent, almost with 10-15 minutes.

> Should I worry if I don't receive a reply tomorrow?

Yeah, you can call them maybe today or tomorrow, as you need to confirm it through a word of mouth, and also clear some doubts yourself. It wouldn't be annoying the HR. In fact, they are paid for that!

Comment: Thanks! I read it 2 hours after it was delivered. I replied immediately after reading it. I don't have their number. Also, they don't have an HR since it's a small startup company. So my interviewer is doing a completely different job. Should I follow up tomorrow?

Comment: @user45100  Even though they are doing a different job, when they send an offer, they need to follow up :)   Yeah, you can follow up with them tomorrow!

Comment: Ok I will. Kinda gets embarrassing since im always the one who follows up and reaches out first after being interviewed by them. I actually started thinking theyre just messing with me haha :/

Comment: Should I follow up tomorrow? According to @Frisbee its xmas week so...

Comment: @user45100  We only have a day off on 25th here in India; so it depends on the place/country where you stay!

Comment: Im in the philippines

Comment: @user45100  If you have a week long vacation for Christmas, then mailing them after that would make sense :)