# Received offer but no reponse from follow up e-mails

Tags: telecommute

I read [this thread](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59762/accepted-job-offer-via-e-mail-no-response-after-when-should-i-follow-up) for reference but I think my situation may be slightly different and I'm unfamiliar if this company culture is relatable to anyone

I recently applied for a company to do remote work from the US but based in Asia. I had received an offer via e-mail with written yearly salary. I had accepted it and called the company boss who interviewed me.

Because of visa and tax laws that required further investigation the company told me they would need to check on their end and would reply back to me within a week.

It's now 2 weeks later and still no reply (even after 2-3 follow up e-mails requesting an update).

Should I assume they decided to drop the offer or is this normal procedure?

Comment: I would say (a) yes it can surely take that long but (b) my guess is you're out of luck in this case and the job has evaporated, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With any employer not responding to e-mails asking for updates concerning a job offer, one can assume they have dropped the offer. The professional thing is to respond to let the applicant know, but depending on the job market and local corporate culture, many employers or hirers either don't have the time or want to make the effort to respond to hires they've decided to drop. Especially with a large number of applicants it's common for hirers to just ignore you.

The alternative is that this was some kind of phishing scam. Consider what information you provided them (bank account number, name and address, phone number?) The fact that you actually talked with some "boss" is not relevant here, it could have just been a call/scam-centre employee pretending to be the company's boss, trying to get extra information from you in person. I'd cross-check with the company website (the possible scammer could have used a real company), try to find out if the phone number you called is on there, perhaps try to send an email request or use a contact form. In this second case your information has probably been added to some database, and you may receive scam phone-calls, emails or texts (including some of your personal information to seem legitimate) in the following months and years.

Comment: +1 for the phishing scam possibility. Definitely something that needs to be considered here.

Comment: Got a reply back 2 weeks later. They:

1.  apologized for the late reply
2.  withdrew the offer because they "couldnt afford to hire me"
3.  asked for my bank number to wire transfer $xxxx amount for compensation.

Comment: I have yet to hear of a company offering "compensation" for not hiring people. That would usually make for a very expensive hiring process! This sounds more and more like a scam and phishing attempt, I would carefully consider before sending your bank account number to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes recruiters give a timeline that's unrealistic and we end up chasing the deadline. Your recruiter should at least get back to you with a "Sorry you haven't heard from me yet, I don't have any updates," but he's likely managing multiple requests and expectations from all sorts of folks. The way I see it, there are three possible scenarios at work:

- Your recruiter is avoiding you because he either has no news, or he has unfavorable news.
- Your recruiter is negligent and is not good at managing email, expectations, or timelines. He may have even forgot to get back to you.
- And this is probably the most likely: he's politicking. he's maneuvering company politics and bureaucracy in order to try to get an update for you or an offer for you. The hiring committee process is pretty infamous. It can drag(stretch) out. He definitely owes you an update, but you may be overthinking this. He may not be "ignoring" you per se. He likely is just trying to get you hired.

Although less likely but I would suggest you to keep continuing your search for the job until you get a formal reply from them.

Meanwhile, you can try mailing the HR team if they've any updates and if the company is Asia based they are more likely to have a support email-id which should help you further.

Finally, I wouldn't stress about it as this just seems a minor delay in the process of hiring. Although until you're sure just keep on trying.